# Load models and related data

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, django-rest-framework, restangular

I'm currently working on a WebApp

Server side :

- [Django [1.7.1]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/)
- [DjangoRestFramwork [2.4.3]](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Client side :

- [AngularJS [1.2.26]](https://angularjs.org/)
- [Restangular [1.4.0]](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

---

My issue is about the relation mapping with the Restangular library.
Exemple : 
 **controller.js**

```
Restangular.all('Cars').getList().then(function(_cars){
    $scope.cars= _cars;
});
```

**_list.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <td>{[project.id]}</td> 
    <td>{[project.owner.name]}</td> <!-- owner is not mapped, (project.owner == ID) -->
</tr>
```

---

My code :

django : **models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    #....
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200)

class Car(models.Model):
    #....
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=True)
```

django : **serializers.py**

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', /*...*/, 'owner')
```

django : **view.py**

```
class CarList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

---

I hope there a way to fully map my object easily, I am not against any other way than the Restangular library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to define a Serializer for `Person` and refer to it in your `CarSerializer`:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Person

    fields = ('id', ...)


# Then use that serializer in CarSerializer:
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = PersonSerializer(source='owner')

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', /*...*/, 'owner')
```

Check the JSON payload using the DRF browsable API to get your desired data.